# Как сделать простановку и удаление символических ссылок автоматом?

Tags: modx, ссылки, revo

В системе **MODX REVO** есть два контекста: web и wap.
Wap контекст нужен для мобильной версии.
В контексте wap сделаны символические ссылки на ресурсы в контексте web.

То есть, зайдя на сайт `m.site.ru/page`,
выводится контент из `site.ru/page`.

Но как быть, если добавляются новые ресурсы в контекст web, он же основной?
Каждый раз лезть в wap контекст и делать вручную ссылку символическую?
Это гемор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На этот случай есть замечательный плагин: https://ilyaut.ru/addons/a-plugin-to-switch-contexts-in-the-absence-of-the-desired-url-in-the-current-context/